# $log(X)$ is normally distributed. how to find CDF of $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

i know that $y = ln(X)$ is normally distributed with a certain mean and standard deviation.

how do i find the CDF of $X$?

suppose my CDF of $y = F(y)$.

my initial idea is that i just calculate $e^{ln(X)}$ because this would give $X$. then i would take this and put it into the CDF for $y$, so $F(x) = F(e^{ln(X)}) = F(x)$. but this is not correct.

another idea that i just came up with is to put the CDF of $y$ into the exponent of $e$, so $e^{F(y)}$. when i do this and visualize it i observe that $e^{F(y)}$ is normally distributed.

is this second approach the correct one? or am i still wrong?

thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDF of $X$ is the probability $F_X(x) = \Pr(X\le x)$.

For $x \le 0$ the probability is zero, and otherwise it's equal to $\Pr(\log X \le \log x) = F_Y(\log x)$.